# Nested class of class template can be "incomplete"

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I'm at a loss as to how to explain why it is valid to create the member `inner` in the class template `OuterTempl<T>` whereas it is illegal to do so in the untemplated class `Outer`.

```
// Non-template version
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner;
    Inner inner;   // incomplete type (I get this)
};

struct Outer::Inner
{
};

// Template version
template<typename T>
struct OuterTempl
{
    struct InnerTempl;
    InnerTempl inner; // OK ... Huh!?
};

template<typename T>
struct OuterTempl<T>::InnerTempl
{
};

int main()
{
}
```

See also [ideone](http://ideone.com/YMeNhI).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - consider [temp.mem.class]/1:

> A member class of a class template may be defined outside the class
>   template definition in which it is declared. 
>   [ *Note:* **The member
>   class must be defined before its first use that requires an
>   instantiation (14.7.1).** For example,
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>     class B;
> };
>
> A<int>::B* b1;  // OK: requires A to be defined but not A::B
>
> template<class T> class A<T>::B { };
>
> A<int>::B b2;   // OK: requires A::B to be defined
> ```
>
> *— end note* ]

It is also important to mention that the definition of `inner`, which constitutes the use of `Inner` the above note describes, is only instantiated once it is required:

> Unless a member […] has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization
>   of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
>   referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist;

Since no instantiation of `OuterTempl` is present in your code, the definition of `inner` is never instantiated, and an instantiation of `Inner` is never necessitated. The completeness of the nested class type for such a declaration is thus only required at the point of instantiation. You don't instantiate `OuterTempl` here, but if you would do that *before the definition of `Inner`*, the code would be ill-formed.

That is,

```
template<typename T>
struct OuterTempl
{
    struct InnerTempl;
    InnerTempl inner;
};

template struct OuterTempl<int>; // Bad - Ill-formed (NDR?)

template<typename T>
struct OuterTempl<T>::InnerTempl {};

template struct OuterTempl<int>; // Fine
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f2ff6ebe043f5a0).

Answer (score 4):

The member types need to be defined when the class is defined. However, a class template doesn't get defined until it gets instantiated. Any kind of dependent types can change till then. The definition of members is only needed when the class gets instantiated.

On the other hand the definition of a non-template class is a definition which needs to know the size of its member at that point.