# Is Clang correct to reject code in which the nested class of a class template is defined only via specializations?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization, incomplete-type

Given the following class template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner;

    auto f(Inner) -> void;
};
```

we define `Inner` separately for each specialization of `Outer`:

```cpp
template<>
struct Outer<int>::Inner {};

template<>
struct Outer<double>::Inner {};
```

and then define the member function `f` once for all specializations of `Outer`:

```cpp
auto Outer<T>::f(Inner) -> void
{

}
```

but Clang (9.0.0) complains:

```cpp
error: variable has incomplete type 'Outer::Inner'

auto Outer<T>::f(Inner) -> void

                      ^
```

We can evade the compiler error by also providing a definition of `Inner` for all other specializations of `Outer`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Outer<T>::Inner {};
```

or by defining `f` separately for each specialization:

```cpp
template<>
auto Outer<int>::f(Inner) -> void
{

}

template<>
auto Outer<double>::f(Inner) -> void
{

}
```

Both GCC and MSVC accept the initial code, which begs the question; is this a Clang bug or is it the only conformant implementation out of the three?

[Try on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/BygJPJ)

Comment: Specialisations of Inner are irrelevant, removing them does not change the compilation result.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I'm not sure what you mean. Both [adding a definition of ```Inner``` for all other specializations](https://godbolt.org/z/zRygaw) and [defining ```f``` separately for each specialization](https://godbolt.org/z/U43aMA) resolve the compilation error.

Comment: Let's read it again: *removing them does not change the compilation result*. Not adding, removing. [gcc](https://ideone.com/vVlix5) [clang](https://ideone.com/pZbUas)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I see what you mean now, but that's still a strange comment to make. The point of my question was that ```Inner``` is being reported as an incomplete type despite definitions for each specialization of ```Outer``` being provided. Clearly ```Inner``` will (correctly) be an incomplete type if you remove its definition(s).

Comment: "Clearly Inner will (correctly) be an incomplete type if you remove its definition(s). " no that"s not ckear at all. A specialisation is a completely separate template and it doesn't affect the main template at all.

Comment: And by the way I'm not sure your specialisations are valid. You are specialising a member without specialising the class itself. From what I hear this is a no-no. But it is irrelevant to the code. The right question about the code is "is an incomplete type in a non-instantiated template an error".

Comment: `class Incomplete;
template <typename T>
void foo(Incomplete){}` gcc/clang reject it, whereas msvc accepts it. (which make me think that clang is right).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I was under the impression that in the definition of ```Outer<T>::f```, the completeness of ```Inner``` is not evaluated until the template is instantiated (since the type of ```Inner``` depends on the template parameter ```T```). Is that not the case? The function signature is really ```template<typename T> auto Outer<T>::f(Outer<T>::Inner) -> void```.

Comment: That was my impression too but apparently clang disagrees.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem.class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760896/nested-class-of-class-template-can-be-incompletemight might be related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Clang is wrong to reject your code. We must ask ourselves, how does your function declaration and definition compare to

```
auto f(typename T::Inner) -> void;

// ...

template<typename T>
auto Outer<T>::f(typename T::Inner) -> void
{ }
```

In this example, `T::Inner` is obviously a dependent type. So Clang may not assume it's incomplete until instantiation. Does the same hold true in your example? I would say so. For we have this in the standard:

> **[temp.dep.type]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.type#5) A name is a *member of the current instantiation* if it is
>
> - An unqualified name that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent
>     base class thereof. [ Note: This can only occur when looking up a name
>     in a scope enclosed by the definition of a class template.  — end
>     note ]
> - ...
>
> A name is a *dependent member of the current instantiation* if it is
>   a member of the current instantiation that, when looked up, refers to
>   at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation.
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.type#9) A type is dependent if it is
>
> - ...
> - a member of an unknown specialization,
> - a nested class or enumeration that is a dependent member of the current instantiation,
> - ...

So the first bullet in paragraph 9 covers the case `typename T::Inner`. That is a dependent type.

Meanwhile your case is covered by the second bullet. `Outer::Inner` is a name that is found in the current instantiation of `Outer`, moreover it's found inside `Outer` itself, and not in a base class. That makes it a dependent member of the current instantiation. This name refers to a nested class. Which means all the conditions in the second bullet apply, thus making `Outer::Inner` a dependent type as well!

Since we have ourselves a dependent type in both cases, compilers should treat them equally as dependent types. My conclusion is that GCC and MSVC are right.

Comment: [Bug reported](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44073). Thanks.