# Is this instance of stateful template metaprogramming well-defined?

Tags: c++

I'm learning stateful template metaprogramming.

I've stumbled upon this example, which I've slightly modified.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace impl
{
    template <typename T>
    struct tag
    {
        friend auto get(tag);
    };

    template <typename T, auto V>
    struct set
    {
        friend auto get(tag<int>) // <-- Originally it was `tag<T>`.
        {
            return V;
        }
    };
}

impl::set<int, 42> x;

int main()
{
    std::cout << get(impl::tag<int>{});
}
```

For some reason, [it works on GCC, but not on Clang.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ1QBXYsg4ByKQGY8tZK2VYA1OO0BhPKgUFimZgFsz2cQAYAgm/e1HmBQAdmdWM8B39WL3EAdlkPY3jjAkww4STTCwIAT39MHwdMYwAVZy8E4xtiZWQCROZgUoTo2PcysqpiPFz0Y2ZlImNgTAIIAjqASjNmsuiAEUnIuISklOY0s3MsnLyCwtIevtRjADUSxfiKqpqFIYb4ptvW9s7abt7%2BweHR%2Bos9Amcx4wAekBxgASphwkECuIAGyuX6w1zGADuhAQpjhxThiUODmYAGsCoQUSR8cY6MZzMJRAA6B7TGL01rxOwEVS0Y7zM6tWYPXnaZq8jxeULhEAga5/H70PbcSTOYwADy5ng8v2MeL0EAmwsZ3Js6HFaD66XM6wGQwgotY4q%2B6wR2hcjKiMwmAsiLo0YyEIA0AFYNKRaL7XIHUL6zTI5OUVGpoZJtJxAwQQ17vfiQNpJDTOFFXJwYTDJAAOTjFuVFn0abiB4MaUOkcMaQMKECuUgp%2Bte0hwWAwRAoVBhPDsMgUCBoYejkDAACcklIVBHSWIrYgACNU6R13pmMRMr6k6RJ/l6AB5WisA9d0hYPGidhb/B2ap4ABufi3mEVmGQfU0Da/JgNo3qweDrsQe6ZOYGCaEetihIe3Y0PQTBsBwPBCCIYhyHIQjga2kDeqg/gEFYtCthoAC0BpmDMEhRjIkjMMYVEAOpsKwrFsd%2BtgsVROToCIZHIFRmDEMQJAKC2sbqFw3ogQGQZbk2irFjCVEwtwAzIMgxizjSkjGBAuCECQpgJpwewwVO4kWYmAKRrIMjJqmYzegg9hYMQlDppmnA0up3CzjCfquPO2hFlEs5%2BlWNakA4IBhcpN5Ni2bYdm5Pb9hASAqAQ/h9OQlCTv4I7iYImD4EQPlWShjAsI%2Bs6kMikH%2BFlim1ipvo6JwKJokq6madpwC6fphmuV27mkJ5zDeb5cWBolyV1g2aWKBlnahtNGaJoFWkhWFEVRTFVbaF1qW%2BpN23ZfAvYDqV5VjiVQ5ldOBjYbOrjtkurArmum43juPj7khx5DqeBAXleT7JNhj43s%2Bv5kR%2BlENt%2Bv7/luQEgQ2YEQVBMFYGDCGJRoSbevVaGPph1I4Yx8j44R2qNqR5GUTRBDoHRDHOdIzHcZx3G8ZBrGCcJeCieJkmrjJqhyZwCm%2Bkpq1hr6akaVpxgfaI42uDSSImdV5m9dZr1PfZkiObhLmZVNfmcN9i0JSAwWBcWQU8JIfraMWs5RDCKVrVdG3tlt3b3blID5YVBDFRO5vTguVVmbVi50A16EgM1rXMO15Pdp1Qdq1oCZGaiBDohrw3a3TesG9daYzV5FUsyB8XLfrnDd9ofrFn6UTcDCjuSLwquNiHrZh25fm9zSIXcOp6ne9F3B92dF3B82dvbUrGiSJvJeN9NH6ruRrtAA)

I don't see anything wrong with the code, yet Clang complains about `get` not being defined:

```
error: function 'get' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
```

Interestingly, if I replace `friend auto get(tag<int>)` with `friend auto get(tag<T>)` it works on both compilers.

What's going on here? Is this example well-defined or not?

---

I tried simplyfing the example as much as possible, and arrived at this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace impl
{
    struct tag {};

    auto get(tag);

    template <auto V>
    struct set
    {
        friend auto get(tag)
        {
            return V;
        }
    };
}

impl::set<42> x;

int main()
{
    std::cout << get(impl::tag{});
}
```

This too only works on GCC.

Comment: Probably related. From http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/ - Note: clang currently has a [bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15481) where `noexcept` does not yield `true` even though the expression checked is a constant-expression.

Comment: Another possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936617/is-clang-correct-to-reject-code-in-which-the-nested-class-of-a-class-template-is).

Comment: It feels icky that gcc is allowing you to declare a specialization without the `<>` marker. I can't imagine how it's not a gcc bug.

Comment: @parktomatomi What specialization?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good point, I was looking at your first example

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - The part where you're declaring `get(tag)` outside a template, but then defining it inside a template, and auto-deducing it with a template argument. What's the correct way to describe that?

Comment: @parktomatomi You mean the lack of `<>` after `tag` in `friend auto get(tag);`? Inside of a class template (`tag<T>`), template arguments after the name of that class can be omitted (e.g. `tag` is equivalent to `tag<T>`).

Comment: Be warned, as always, that the committee [abhors this technique](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118) and has recently even made a bit of (not yet visible) progress on unmaking it.

Comment: Now the program is accepted by all compilers including Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/W9ea35efd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in Clang starting with Clang 12 (thanks @Fedor), so this was most probably a Clang bug.